# Not able to Trigger Composer DAG using Cloud Function on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am working on a requirement where I want to trigger a DAG using cloud function.
I am using composer version 2,and cloud function Gen 1.

I have tried using the code that was given on google documentation, but it's not working.
So, I am directly sending request to REST api.
below is my cloud function code:

```
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests


# getting the credentials and project details for gcp project
credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"])

#getting request object
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

# print(credentials.token) # prints token

def trigger(event_data, context):
  u="https://800f896i9ecbkf3bi48jffee426b9994-dot-us-central1.composer.googleusercontent.com/api/v1/dags/reporting/dagRuns/"

  response = requests.get(
    url=u,
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {credentials.token}'}
        )
# print(response)
```

where reporting is my DAG name.

But,I am not getting any error, the response code is 200.
Below is the success message in logs:

```
 "Function execution took 243 ms, finished with status: 'ok'"
```

But, DAG is not getting triggered.

The service account which cloud function is using have below roles:
.Cloud Composer v2 API Service Agent Extension
.Composer User
.Service Account User
.IAP-secured Web App User
.Storage Object Viewer

Can anyone help.

Comment: This is possibly a quota issue, even if that is not the case I would suggest to contact Google for your inquiry as they have better vsibility on your logs and resource usage. https://cloud.google.com/contact